# Is using C functions instead of static methods for making pure functions a bad design?

Tags: objective-c

If I am implementing a function that does some calculation based on certain input and returns the output without causing any side effects.

I always use Regular C functions instead of having static methods in a class.

Is there a rationale behind using static methods forcefully put into a class ?

I am not talking about methods that create singletons or factory methods but the regular methods like there:

Instead of having something like this:

```
+(NSString *)generateStringFromPrefixString:(NSString *)prefixString word:(NSString *)word;
```

won't this be better ?

```
NSString *generateString(NSString *prefixString, NSString *word);
```

In terms of efficiency also, wont we be saving, lookup for the selector to get the function pointer ?

Comment: I certainly prefer C functions in some cases for their brevity and clarity.  Eg, a trig function is much better as `trigFunc(someVal)` vs `[TrigClass trigFunc:someVal]`.  But these are the exceptions.  Knowing how to use tools is not about knowing never to use a screwdriver for a chisel, but knowing *when* it's appropriate to use a screwdriver for a chisel.

Comment: You haven't given the second parameter a name. Bad form, sir.

Comment: @Abizern: Done! Shakespeare once said, "What's in a name?", I hope he was an Objective C compiler :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is bad design, no, but there are certain circumstances where one may be considered more appropriate than the other. The key questions are:

- Does this method belong to a class?
- Is this method worth adding to a class?

A class is something that is self-contained and reusable. For the method in your example, I would be tempted to answer "Yes, it does/is," because it is something specific to `NSString` and is a method you (presumably) want to use fairly often. Its parameters are also of type `NSString`. I would therefore use the message form in a class extension and `#import` the extension when you need it.

There are two situations (off the top of my head) where this is not really appropriate. Firstly is the situation where the method interacts specifically with other entities outside of the 'main class'. Examples of this can be found near the bottom of Apple's `NSObjcRuntime.h` file. These are all standard C functions. They don't really belong to a specific class.

The second situation to use a standard C function is when it will only be used once (or very few times) in a very specific circumstance. `UIApplicationMain` is the perfect example, and helper methods for a specific `UIView` subclass's `-drawRect:` method also come to mind.

A final point on efficiency. Yes, selector lookup is fractionally slower standard C calls. However, the runtime (Apple's at least, can't comment on GCC's) does use a caching system so that the most commonly sent messages quickly gravitate to the 'top' of the selector table.

*Disclaimer:* This is somewhat a question of a style and the above recommendations are the way I would do it as I think it makes code more organised and readable. I'm sure there are other equally valid ways to structure/interleave C and Objective-C code.

Comment: I don't know what counts as fractionally slower, last time I heard statistics on this from Apple, methods were about 1.5 time the speed of slowest form of calling a c function. When you add the fact that functions can have optimisations applied to speed them up, inline some form of inlining, using c functions instead of methods is a valid approach to code that may be called frequently. I have some Objective-C projects where I will have C functions in place of the primate methods, though there maybe objective-C public methods.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C doesn't have such a thing as "static methods". It has class methods. This isn't just picking a nit because class methods are dispatched dynamically, not statically. And that can be one reason to use a class method rather than a function: it allows for subclasses to override it.

By contrast, that can also be a reason to use a function rather than a class method – to prevent it from being overridden.

But, in general, there's no rule that you have to use class methods. If a function suits your needs and your preferences, use a function.

Answer (score 2):

One important factor is **testability**. Does your c-functions specifically need testing? (off-course everything has to be ideally tested, but sometimes you just can test a thing by calling what calls it). If you need to, can you access those functions individually?
Maybe you need to mock them to test other functionality?

As of 2013, if you live in the Apple/Xcode/iOS/MacOS world, it is much more likely you have more built-in tools for testing things in objc than plain c. What I am trying to say is: ***Mocking of c-functions is harder***.

I like very much C functions. At first I didn't like them to be in my good-looking objc code. After a while, I thought that doesn't matter too much. What it really matters is the context. My point is (as same as PLPiper's on NSObjcRuntime.h) that sometimes, by judging by its name or functionality, a function does not belong to any class. So there is no semantic reason to make them a class method. All this ambiguous-like thing went away when I started writing tests for code that contained several **inline** c functions. Now, if I need some c function be specifically tested, mocked, etc. I know it is easier to do it in objc. There are more/easier built-in tools for testing objc things that c.

For the interested: [Function mocking (for testing) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959132/function-mocking-for-testing-in-c)

Comment: The testability concern is certainly valid. If one makes a rule to only write pure functions in C--functions with no side effects, where the result can be known deterministically from the input (like the CGGeometry functions)--then there's probably little need to mock the functions, and they should be pretty easy to unit test directly as well.

Comment: Right, you explained it better than me. :)

Answer (score 0):

For sake of consistency and programmer expectation, i'd say to use Objective C style. I'm no fan of mixing calling notation and function notation, but your mileage may differ.

Comment: If you look at Core Graphics, there are a methods like CGRectMaake and CGPointMake.

Comment: Yes, but core graphics is entirely C style and therefore consistent.